# SSDT Not Working In Visual Studio 2010 SP1

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

I'm running Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Premium on Windows 7, and am trying to create SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) Reports. I've downloaded the new SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027 and installed/restarted. If I go into VS Help->About, I can see "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools 10.3.20225.0" in the list of installed products. However, SSDT doesn't seem to be showing up in the "New Project" window, and if I try to open existing SSRS 2005 reports projects (created in BIDS/VS 2005) it says "'Reports.rptproj' cannot be opened because its project type (.rptproj) is not supported by this version of the application. To open it, please use a version that supports this type of project".

Am I incorrect in my impression that VS/SSDT does not require SQL Server being installed? Is there some other software, package, or step that I'm missing in installing SSDT?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For SQL Server 2012 SSRS, the functionality of BIDS is REPLACED by SSDT.  If you are working with SQL Server 2008 R2 (or earlier) SSRS, then you'll want to use BIDS from that version of SQL Server.

When you install SSDT, it includes templates for BI projects (i.e. SSAS, SSIS, SSRS).  SSDT can be installed as a stand-alone application, or, if you have VS2010 SP1 on your machine, then SSDT will install inside of VS2010.

For the OLTP (including offline) database projects, there is NO template.  Rather there is a new View named 'SQL Server Object Explorer'.  For more about the latter, see my [blog post](http://lynnlangit.wordpress.com/2011/11/21/sql-server-2012sql-server-data-tools/).

Comment: Interestingly, when I installed SSDT I did get the new SQL object explorer view installed in VS 2010 SP1, but did not get the new templates. Our production SQL server is running SQL 2005, but my dev machine is running VS2010. Is there no way to edit/create reports in VS2010, but have it "target" SSRS 2005? (Similar to multi-targeting older .NET frameworks)

Comment: unfortunately the targeting in SSDT is only for the OLTP engine at this time

Comment: The SSDT database stuff and the SSDT BIDS stuff are somewhat separate.  It is something of a name game MS is playing.  This post has details on how to get both installed: http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2012/04/ssdt-installation-confusion/

Comment: @AaronLS: That link did the best job of explaining why things weren't working for me. While I had the SSDT-DB shell for VS installed (from the MSDN SSDT download), I still needed to install SQL2012 in order to get the SSDT-BIDS portion for VS. Lynn's answer, along with Aaron's comment solved my problem.

Answer (score 6):

The new project type is found under **Other Languages**->SQL Server-> SQL Sever Database Project.

**Do not confuse** that with the old to be deprecated projects under Database->SQL Server->Advanced

The BIDS part of SSDT is sort of a separate install.  (although they've tried making it seem like one install.)  See this on information about why one or the other might not be installed:

http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2012/04/ssdt-installation-confusion/

Comment: I created a new project under SQL Server->SQL Server Database Project (I don't have a category called "Other Languages", but still don't see a way to create reports.

Comment: It is my understanding that BIDS was last compatible with VS 2008, and is being phased out in favour of SSDT. In fact, official infographics from Microsoft state that SSDT will contain the components formerly within BIDS (cf http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2011/07/sql-server-%E2%80%9Cdenali%E2%80%9D-sql-server-developer-tools-codename-juneau/), while the SQL 2012 installer claims that SSDT is a replacement for BIDS (cf http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2012/04/03/ssdt-what-s-in-a-name.aspx). If BIDS is no longer being developed, and SSDT won't open rptprj files, am I stuck?

Comment: @Adam, you can install the 2008R2 BIDS stuff and it will continue too work for 2008R2.  While they have played some games with the product name, they aren't doing anything to disable that, so no you are not stuck.  If you want the BI components for 2012, then I recommend you read this post: http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2012/04/ssdt-installation-confusion/

Comment: @Adam Recommend this article as well http://svenaelterman.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/when-ssdt-is-not-ssdt/